# I have to set layout of print. material exceed from A4 page

Tags: html, css, angular, angular6

I made chalan format with 3 copies and wanted to print on same page right now 2 copies print correctly but 3rd one is not display on page.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: this is screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see the scrollbar on your print, there must be a `overflow: scroll` somewhere in your style which must be set to `overflow: visible` in your print styles, so that all your content will be printed

Comment: hi adrian, thanks for your reply but its not working for me because i want to print all material. please see the screenshot on top. scroll is not a problem in my case

Comment: on your print a scrollbar is shown, so i'm almost sure it's an overflow issue, could you provide some code?
Would make it much easier to help

Comment: i dont have issue with scroll bar my main concern is all material is not an printable form. please see ss above